# Babel and Webpack es6 errors, tried numerous fixes found here but cant get it working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I keep getting errors when trying to use react with my flask website. I've tried a ton of fixes I found here, but whenever I move past one, another one pops up.

Most recent error is:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected Token (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* DayPicker styles */
| 
> .DayPicker {
|   display: inline-block;
|   font-size: 1rem;
 @ ./js/daypicker.js 17:0-41
 @ ./js/index.js
```

I tried adding in CSS and Style loaders, as can be seen below, but I can't get it working. My code may be messy, but its because I've been trying a bunch of different fixes, and some of them have been overlaid by others.

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  entry: {
    index: './js/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/lib'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/static/lib'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'style-loader',
          loader: 'css-loader',
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0', 'env'],
          }
        }
      },

    ]
  }
};
```

I even tried addring a babel.rc file (as suggested in some fixes found here):

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true'
}
```

But nothing seems to work

Not sure if this is relevant, but here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "shopping-cart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "run `npm install`. and then `npx webpack`",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -w",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/pambalos/shopping-cart.git"
  },
  "author": "Bradley J <bradleyjusticeca@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/pambalos/shopping-cart/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/pambalos/shopping-cart#readme",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "date-fns": "next",
    "moment": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.2.4",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-helmet": "latest",
    "webpack": "^4.28.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: try this: `{
      test: /\.css$/,  
      include: /node_modules/,  
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
 }`

Comment: Try it in my babel.rc file or my webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Try it in webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks! I threw it in my webpack.config.js file and it seems to be working! Can you explain this solution a bit so I can understand whats going on for future occasions?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, we can use the `style-loader and css-loader` in the webpack.config.js, like below:

```js
{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  include: /node_modules/, 
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] 
}
```

`css-loader` reads in a css file as a string. Since it just reads the file contents and nothing else, it's basically useless unless you chain it with another loader.

`style-loader` takes those styles and creates a  tag in the page's  element containing those styles.

Hope it helps :)